# jQuery poll-vote plugin without pHp utilization?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, asp-classic

I am trying to find a plugin or widget type jQuery script I can implement with my website to utilize a **voting poll** on individual pages.  I do not have access to the site server as I am using a Volusion shopping cart which uses .asp pages not pHp.

Anyone know where I would start looking for something like this or how it would store the information for that matter?

Comment: The jQuery just passes requests to the server, it doesn't have to be PHP. What plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to make a poll using JavaScript alone. JavaScript is client-side and the poll results have to get stored somewhere.

With ASP, however, it's possible:

- [ASPPoll](http://www.toddwoolums.com/asppoll.asp)
- [ASP Poll / Voting Code](http://www.aspisfun.com/code/poll/)